# How to get rid of INCOMPLETE STRING error in ShinyApp R?

Tags: r, string, shiny

All brackets seems to be fine, bt I still receive an error

```
"Error in parse(file, keep.source = FALSE, srcfile = src, encoding = enc) : 
  C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/WIZD/Początek shiny.R:3:15: unexpected INCOMPLETE_STRING
2: ui <- pageWithSidebar(
3:   headerPanel("Emisja zanieczyszczel
                 ^
Error in 'sourceUTF8(fullpath, envir = new.env(parent = sharedEnv))':
  Error sourcing C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpkRrkjr\file679855416f8c
```

Do you have any ideas what can be wrong?

```
library(shiny)
ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Emisja zanieczyszczeń przez samochody 2000-2013", windowTitle = "..."),
              sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(
                  helpText("Informacja na temat zanieczyszczeń emitowanych przez 
                           samochody w zależności od ich producenta."),
                  selectInput(inputId = "marka", 
                              label="Wybierz producenta samochodowego", 
                              choices=c("BMW","Honda", "Hyundai","Fiat", "Skoda", "Toyota"),
                              selected="BMW"),
                  sliderInput(inputId = "year", 
                              label="Wybierz rok", 
                              min=2000, max=2013, value=c(2000,2013))), 
              mainPanel(plotOutput("boxplot"))))
server<-function(input, output){}
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing shiny layouts. If you use [`pageWithSidebar`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.0/pageWithSidebar.html) then you need to provide a `headerPanel`, a `sidebarPanel` and a `mainPanel`. But when you try to provide the `sidebarPanel` you did it with `sidebarLayout`. That's not necessary and probably what is causing the problem. Try this:

```
ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Emisja zanieczyszczeń przez samochody 2000-2013", windowTitle = "..."),
  sidebarPanel(
    helpText("Informacja na temat zanieczyszczeń emitowanych przez 
                           samochody w zależności od ich producenta."),
    selectInput(inputId = "marka", 
                label="Wybierz producenta samochodowego", 
                choices=c("BMW","Honda", "Hyundai","Fiat", "Skoda", "Toyota"),
                selected="BMW"),
    sliderInput(inputId = "year", 
                label="Wybierz rok", 
                min=2000, max=2013, value=c(2000,2013))
  ), 
  mainPanel(plotOutput("boxplot"))
)
```